# Proving limit of $\sqrt{n} (\sqrt[n]{n} -1)$ is $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I managed to prove that limit to $\sqrt[n]{n} -1$ tends to $0$, but couldn't go anywhere from there. Could somebody help?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @Mattos Please be respect to the new contributor. He is new, ok?

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio Showing your own efforts is completely necessary for asking a good question, new user notwithstanding.

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio Nowhere in my previous comment was I disrespectful. Next time, when you read a comment, you might want to take a second and consider whether _you_ are misinterpreting someones response.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
\ln(\sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)) &= \ln(\sqrt{n}) + \ln(\exp{\frac{\ln(n)}{n} -1})\\
&= \ln(\sqrt{n}) + \ln(\frac{\ln(n)}{n} + o(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}))\\
&= \ln(\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} + o(\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}) \rightarrow - \infty
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\sqrt{n}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1) \rightarrow 0
$$
as $n \rightarrow + \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

By considering the graph of $y=e^x$ we see that, for sufficiently small $x$,  $$1+x\le e^x <1+2x$$ $$x\le e^x-1 <2x.$$
Now let $x=\frac{\ln n}{n}$, then  $e^x=n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and so $$\frac{\ln n}{n} \le n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1<2\frac{\ln n}{n}$$ $$\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n} \le \sqrt n(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)<2\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt n}.$$ Therefore $\sqrt n(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n} (\sqrt[n]{n} -1)=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{1/n} -1}{n^{-1/2}}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{1/n}(n^{-2}(1-\ln n))}{(-1/2)n^{-3/2}}=\\
\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n-1}{(1/2)n^{1/2}}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{-1}}{(1/4)n^{-1/2}}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(1/4)n^{1/2}}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Formally substitute $n=1/x$, so to get
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{1}{x^x}-1\right)=\frac{1}{x^x}\frac{1-x^x}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
If $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$ exists, then it is the same as $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(1/n)$, which is what you want to compute.

Note that the factor $1/x^x$ can be disregarded, because it has limit $1$ as $x\to0^+$. Thus we can just compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1-x^x}{\sqrt{x}}\overset{(\mathrm{H})}{=}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^x(1+\log x)}{1/(2\sqrt{x})}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x(2\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{x}\log x)
$$
(where $\overset{(\mathrm{H})}{=}$ denotes application of l'Hôpital). Now we only have to compute, with the substitution $y=\sqrt{x}$,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\sqrt{x}\log x=\lim_{y\to0^+}2y\log y=0
$$
(a well known fact).

Hence the final limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n^{1/n}=1+x_n.$ We have $$n\ge 3\implies x_n>0 \quad \text {(obviously)}.$$ We have $$n\ge 3 \implies n=(1+x_n)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom {n}{j}(x_n)^j>\binom {n}{3}(x_n)^3\implies$$ $$\implies 1>\frac {1}{n}\binom {n}{3}(x_n)^3=\frac {(n-1)(n-2)}{6}(x_n)^3>\frac {(n/3)^2}{6}(x_n)^3\implies$$ $$\implies \frac {54^{1/3}}{n^{2/3}}>x_n\implies$$ $$\implies 0<\sqrt n\,(n^{1/n}-1)=\sqrt n\cdot x_n<\sqrt n \cdot \frac {54^{1/3}}{ n^{2/3}}=\frac {54^{1/3}}{n^{1/6}}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Using l'Hôpital's rule, the derivative of $f(n)=\sqrt{n} (\sqrt[n]{n} -1)$ is:

$$
f'(n)=n^{1/n + 1/2} \frac{1-\log(n)}{n^2} + \frac{\sqrt[n]{n} -1}{2 \sqrt{n}}.
$$

Now taking $\displaystyle  \lim_{n\to\infty}$ of the above expression, we get $\displaystyle 0 + \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\sqrt[n]{n} -1}{2 \sqrt{n}}$, and we know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1$, which yields the desired result.

Comment: Isn't l'Hôpital's taking the derivative of 2 parts of an expression, not the entire expression?